# See number of changes made

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code full of str.contains. The conditions are changed frequently after checking the results. I would like to see the number of changes made without typing each condition twice. When typing and changing many conditions, having to copy it each line twice is messy and confusing. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
df.loc[df.str.contains("apple"), "category"] = "fruit"
df.loc[df.str.contains("banana"), "category"] = "fruit"
df.loc[df.str.contains("Samsung|Sony"), "category"] = "Technology"
```

Expected Output:

```
apple replacement yielded 30 changes
banana replacement yielded 57 changes
Samsung|Sony replacement yielded 0 changes
```

Comment: Just write a function and let it do the "messy and confusing" bit for you.

Answer (score 1):

It change if match `True`s values, so for count `True` use `sum` of condition:

```
L = ["apple", "banana", "Samsung|Sony"]

for x in L:
    f'{x} replacement yielded {df['col'].str.contains(x).sum()} changes'
```

If need optimalize your solution:

```
d = {"banana|banana":"fruit", "Samsung|Sony":"Technology"}
for k,  v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['col'].str.contains(k), "category"] = v
```